# Which type should i use for html text in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, tinymce

I have a text area plugged in with tinyMCE which will contain HTML code that I wish to save into the database.

I want to save that html code right as it is, to be able to print it anytime, and even to be able to write it down to a file `(using fopen("filename","w"); )`

Since i'm setting up the table I will be using, i do not know which type of record should I assign to this html text in my database.

Should I..:

- use `addslashes/stripslashes` when I save/stamp the html text?
- or `htmlencodechars/decodechars`?
- or none at all?

Comment: Escape at the last possible moment. Parametrize your queries to insert html safely, and then, when outputting it, encode it.

Comment: ok, but should i use a varchar field? or a longtext? or even a blob? the content written down will be a journal article, so it will be long, as one of those... also, when i do encode/decode, wich should i use? htmlencodechars or addslashes?
thanks for the infos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to strip any malicious XSS code from the HTML. TinyMCE tries to do this but it can be bypassed by posting directly to your script.

When storing the data, use a parameterised query/prepared statement instead of escaping, to prevent SQL Injection. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) can do that. [This is a good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), especially if you're coming from the native mysql_* library.

As for the datatype, any string type is fine, it depends on how long your content could be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this with arkascha answear actually solved my problem, look up for the tutorial, so i will be able to use it efficently ^^

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) data type for storing the HTML, and parametrized queries with PDO or mysqli instead of `addslashes`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a large varchar such as varchar(5000) means you will be able to do full text indexing, where on a TEXT column you would not.

If would be much safer to use something like BBcode markup instead but if you have to use HTML (hopefully not allowing guests to input it) there are plugins like http://htmlpurifier.org/ that do a good job of sanitizing HTML.

Obviously you can encode and decode the HTML using the standard PHP functions but there is always the risk of letting something through.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use type 'text' for the column in the database and some database abstraction layer that takes over the encosing for you, like PDO.

`htmlencodechars()` and `addslashes()` are both not suitable. It is not important to do some encoding, but to do the right type of encoding for the given purpose.

Comment: thx for your answear, i have never heard of a database abstraction layer, so could you help me getting started there? i'm currently reading PDO php manual, but i don't quite get it, so if you could summarize the rope up i would appreciate it..., thanks again

Comment: Short summary: you create an query object by giving it a 'raw' sql template, that is a template with 'placeholders' (":valuename") inside, the placeholders are later replaced by the query object. You start execution by handing over an assoiative array of values, unescaped values. The PDO object makes the escaping for you, depending on what is actually required for the database type currently in use. Much more features, but those are the basics. Take a look at the examples, it is not that difficult.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm gonna try it up and see what i will be able to do, so basically pdo do the escaping and allow me to pass variable sql-injection-safely? that's a great addon from the last time i coded in php ! :)